# CSRF token for API serving application

Tags: web-application, csrf, api

Currently, my architecture as follows.

- API is served from `api.domain.com`.
- Frontend application is served from `frontend.domain.com`.

I'm concidering two different methods for CSRF protection:

1. Letting the frontend acquire a CSRF token by making a request to `api.domain.com/getCSRF` after it loads the first time.
2. Enable CORS on my `api.domain.com` and allow request only from `frontend.domain.com`.

I found a major website using my first approach to get the CSRF token, but I don't think it's a good approach. Which one of my methods is better for CSRF protection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need both:

- Just #1 alone, without any CORS policy, would not allow the frontend to read the responses. And if you set a to generous CORS policy, it would allow  anyone included in it to CSRF you.
- Just #2 alone would not offer CSRF protection. You do not need CORS permission to send normal non-preflighted requests, such as submitting an ordinary form. Attacks could still be mounted from any domain. CORS does not protect against CSRF because it's not designed to.

Together they work. The token ensures that only "non-forged" requests are allowed, and the CORS policy ensures that only the frontend can get it's hands on the token.

I should also mention that in situations like this, with an API serving a frontend, CSRF protection often comes "automatically" because a bearer token in the auth header (as opposed to a cookie) is used. So if that's your authentication scheme, you may already be protected. Implementing another layer of defence on that doesn't hurt, though.

Comment: " Attacks could still be mounted from any domain" but if maid  request with curl what happens here

Comment: @iambatman Remember that in a CSRF attack, it is the victims browser that sends the "forged" request. CURL is not relevant.

Comment: @Yes your assumption was correct one more doubt

Comment: "because a bearer token in the auth header is used"I am using the same way but the auth cookie is not exposed to javascript instead i am sending it with each request

Comment: @iambatman If you are using a cookie, you need explicit CSRF protection. Cookies, unlike header values, are sent automatically by the browser.

Comment: In short, I need CSRF protection??

Comment: @iambatman Yes, you need CSRF protection.

Comment: One more doubt if I enabled only cors with allowing from my front end domain only I am still vulnerable to CSRF attacks??

Comment: @iambatman Yes. *CORS does not protect against CSRF.*

Comment: if I switched to token-based authentication, on every request will attach the token in the request header for that I need to store it in a cookie (Httponly false) ,but if I am under XSS vulnerability my token is exposed??

Comment: @iambatman I think this is starting to get unrelated to your original question. If you have questions about token based authentication, I recommend you ask a new one.